# Convert everything between <tag></tag> to HTML enitites with PHP

Tags: php, html-entities

How could I convert everyting between a tag to html enities:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<code class="highlight sql">
    CREATE TABLE `comments`
</code>

<h1>Next step</h1>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
<b>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus</b> est Lorem
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua:
<code class="highlight php">
    <?php
        $host = "localhost";
    ?>
</code>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
```

Note: That example above is a string which I could convert in PHP.

Comment: Could you give a better example with more realistic data?

Comment: Download a syntax highlighting plugin/library. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Phil: Added. See above.

Comment: @Dan: I'm using already a syntax highlighting plugin. But I need to convert the code inside the <code> tags to enities to have valid html code.

Comment: @Poru How is that string generated?

Comment: @Phil: Fetched from database.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid HTML code"? What is wrong with just outputting that?

Comment: Is the entire string the content of a blog post or something? If this is supposed to be html output, it should be stored already escaped properly in the first place.

Comment: @NullUserException: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059776/include-source-code-in-html-valid/7059834

Comment: @Wesley Murch: It's the content of a tutorial. It's an own development "CMS".

Comment: @Wesley Murch: Storing text with html entities does not look like a good practice to me... what if you want to search your database for "Grégoire"? Are you going to look for "Gr&eacute;goire"?

Comment: @greg0ire: You misunderstood, I meant that if this is for HTML output it needs to be stored as such, escaped where appropriate. A search should not take this data verbatim. If I search for `sql class`, some HTML with `class="highlight sql"` (which will not be visible, nor is it content) should **not** be a result. Search functions are another beast altogether. And with UTF-8, no need to encode everything to entities, just HTML characters - so "Grégoire" can remain the way it is (besides the point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to a regex for me. And before you start shouting it is possible to reliably match & replace subsets of html, as long as there are no nesting tags.

This is the easy way tbh. A regex to match a tag start till end and apply a function to the matches / encoding what we need and replacing it.

Heres the code:

```
<?php
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<code class="highlight sql">
    CREATE TABLE `comments`&
</code>

<h1>Next step</h1>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
<b>Stet clita kasd gubergren&, no sea takimata sanctus</b> est Lorem
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy " eirmod " tempor invidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliq&uyam erat, sed diam voluptua:
<code class="highlight php">
    <?php
       * $host = "localhost";
    ?>&
</code>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.';

echo preg_replace("/(<code[^>]*?>)(.*?)(<\/code>)/se", "
    stripslashes('$1').
    htmlentities(stripslashes('$2')).
    stripslashes('$3')
", $string);
```

And heres a working testcase on codepad

http://codepad.org/MhKwfOQl

This will work as long as there are no nasty nested tags / corrupted html.

I would still advise you to try and make sure you save the data as you want to make it visible, encoded where needed.

If you want to replace between a different set of tags change the regex.

**Update:** It seemed that $host was being parsed by php... and ofrourse we don't want this. This happened because php evaluates the replacement string as php which then executes the given functions and inputs the found strings into those functions, and if that string is encapsulated by double qoutes it will parse those strings too... heh what a hassle.

And another problem then arises, php escapes single and double qoutes in matches so they won't generate parse errors, this ment that any qoutes in the matches had to be stripped from their slashes too... resulting in the pretty long replace string.

Comment: haha :) You copied my idea. OK, I haven't copyrighted it. It is very likely that this is what he needs. The question author hasn't specified if he need a solution for a specific TAG or just for any text between tags. So you can be right.

Comment: I actually started out right away with what you had minus tag wildcards but it didn't work because I forgot that I had to use the e modifier on my regex, yeah thats pretty stupid. Wasted some time in the process of 'debugging' that too :s

Comment: Why have you added `[^>]`? It doesn't make sense, because this will not work with simple `<code>` tag. I think it would be a better idea to add `\b` instead.

Comment: @Karolis works fine if I see this correctly: http://codepad.org/a8N14aoo or maybe you mean something else? That tag ensures the regex accepts any attributes on the tag, so the `class="... etc` until it encounters a single >

Comment: Oh, pardon. I haven't noticed that there is no dot after the `]` in your regexp. Ok. So I am deleting my answer in favour of yours.

Comment: That's mostly fine :)! Just the $host variable is removed? Also in your working testcase. Could you check it again?

Comment: You're right, sorry I missed it, php probably sees that as a normal variable at some point, gimme a sec to make a fix.

Comment: @Poru Sorry it took a little long I had to launch a site in the mean time, anyway it should work now, updated the andwer.

Answer (score 1):

Although a regular expression or parser may give you a solution to this puzzle, I think you may be going about your goal the wrong way.

> <sub>Taken from the comments below the question:</sub>
>
> @Poru How is that string generated?
>
> @Phil: Fetched from database. It's
> the content of a tutorial. It's an own development "CMS".

If you are storing this string in a database, and it's function is to return HTML content, you should be storing the content ready to serve as HTML, which means you must escape the appropriate characters with their equivalent HTML entities.

This was the advice already offered to you in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059776/include-source-code-in-html-valid/7059834

The characters that must be escaped are explained here (among other various references):

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
>
> The translations performed are:
>
> - '&' (ampersand) becomes `'&amp;'`
> - '"' (double quote) becomes `'&quot;'` when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> - "'" (single quote) becomes `'&#039;'` only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> - '<' (less than) becomes `'&lt;'`
> - '>' (greater than) becomes `'&gt;'`

If in fact this is the case, and this string is supposed to be HTML output and has no other function, it doesn't make any sense to save it as invalid HTML, or at least not what you intend it to be.

If you *must* store your code examples unescaped, consider a separate database table for these snippets, and simply run [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on them before outputting it to the HTML document. You could even assign a language to each record, and use the appropriate syntax highlighting tool for each case automatically.

What you are attempting, in my opinion, is not the appropriate solution to this particular problem, in this context. Escaping the characters and having your HTML content ready to be output to screen in it's current form is the way to go.

Comment: This would adress the underlying problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(...);

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tag');
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $tag->nodeValue = htmlentities($tag->nodeValue);
}
$dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: DOMDocument is nice but will wreak havok on your page with warnings when it's not used with well formed html...

Comment: True enough, but everyone should be writing well-formed HTMl these days, right? If need be, there's always Tidy.

Comment: What if you're not dealing with a full document? But maybe a part of it... Like generating a single block worth of content. Anyway I tested it and it messes up at the php tags / destroys data... Well I supose you could always pull the whole output buffer through those functions :p

Comment: You can always import an html snippet into a blank dom document, if need be. This iwas just an example anyways. It's a bit much to expect DOM to be PHP-aware anyways. OP would have to run the block of text through PHP first to evaluate all the code, THEN use DOM for the entity conversion.